# Remove parent page from url

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

I would like to remove the parent page name from the permalink.

At the moment, I have site.com/parent-page/child-page.php

and I would like to have something like that site.com/child-page.php

Comment: use the custom permalinks instead of a plugin, from Setting->Permalinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a plugin [Custom Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/) to the rescue. But you have to change the permalink page by page.